# Xpath with Contain text()

Tags: xpath

Can someone please help me in writing the XPath for the Edit Button for the Following code?

```
<td class aria-describedby="b6b00604-67ec-4313-874c-af9373250b47" role="gridcell">
    <div> How Do I Complain about Water Problem?</div>
    <a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext btn-xs k-grid-Edit"href="#">Edit</a>
</td>
```

I've tried:

```
//td[contains(text(),'How Do I Complain about Water Problem?')]/..//a[@class='k-button k-button-icontext btn-xs k-grid-Edit']
```

Comment: td class aria-describedby="b6b00604-67ec-4313-874c-af9373250b47" role="gridcell">
<div> How Do I Complain about Water Problem?</div>

<a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext btn-xs k-grid-Edit"href="#">Edit</a>
</td>

Comment: I have written Xpth as followsfor the Edit button .but its not working                             
//td[contains(text(),'How Do I Complain about Water Problem?')]/..//a[@class='k-button k-button-icontext btn-xs k-grid-Edit']

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is wrong. You're trying to select `td` by text child while actually `"How Do I Complain about Water Problem?"` is text child of `div` not `td`. Try this one:

```
//td[div=" How Do I Complain about Water Problem?"]/a[.="Edit"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your Help. but Your answer is not working.                                      <td class="" aria-describedby="ce5a54e1-6b3a-4f57-b533-edcab6370f34" role="gridcell"><div>How Do I Complain about Water Problem?</div></td>                                                                                                              <a role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext btn-xs k-grid-Edit" href="#">Edit</a>

Comment: @DiliniGunawardhane In your question there was a space before "How Do I Complain about Water Problem?". Try to remove that space in XPath: `//td[div="How Do I Complain about Water Problem?"]/a[.="Edit"]`